# How to get specific values from a list of multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
I have a list of dictionaries as 

    check_list = [{'datasource_path': 'Checks/',
      'Result': True,
      'kwargs': {'column_name': 'car_id', 'd_type': 'int', 'table': 'cars/'},
      'type': 'check_datatype'},
     {'datasource_path': 'Checks1/',
       'Result': False,
      'kwargs': {'column_name': 'customer_id', 'd_type': 'str', 'table': 'cars1/'},
      'type': 'check_datatype1'}]
    
I was trying this:  

     res = [[i for i in check_dict[x]] for x in check_dict.keys()] 
     print("The list values of keys are : " + str(res)) 
    
what I want to get as output is list of lists as below:
    
    [[ Checks/,True,'cars/',check_datatype],[
```

Checks1/,False,'cars1/',check_datatype1]]

```
I have one more use case where the below function takes 'type' as argument 
and returns the corresponding value as per dictionary 

def getType(self,type):
        check_dict={'check_datatype':'M1','check_datatype1':'C1'
                    }
        return check_dict[test_case_name]
```

I want to append this dictionary values M1 and C1 as per the type also in
all the lists output. Final Output should be like below -

```
[['Checks/', True, 'cars/', 'check_datatype','M1'], ['Checks1/', False, 
'cars1/', 'check_datatype1','C1']]
```

Comment: I'm not able to get what is the difference between output you got and what you want but you should not use `str(res)` rather use a `,` instead of `+` in your print statement. Hope that solves the problem. So it should be `print('The values are: ', res)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use list comprehension as:

```
lst = [{'datasource_path': 'Checks/',
  'Result': True,
  'kwargs': {'column_name': 'car_id', 'd_type': 'int', 'table': 'cars/'},
  'type': 'check_datatype'},
 {'datasource_path': 'Checks1/',
   'Result': False,
  'kwargs': {'column_name': 'customer_id', 'd_type': 'str', 'table': 'cars1/'},
  'type': 'check_datatype1'}]

res = [[elt['datasource_path'], elt['Result'], elt['kwargs']['table'], 
       elt['type']] for elt in lst]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[['Checks/', True, 'cars/', 'check_datatype'], ['Checks1/', False, 'cars1/', 'check_datatype1']]
```

Just using `keys()` will not work as it is a nested dictionary so `keys()` will  give only level of keys.

---

Update: Add another element based on the datatype.

```
def getType(check_type): 
    check_dict={'check_datatype':'M1','check_datatype1':'C1' } 
    return check_dict[check_type] 

res = [[elt['datasource_path'], elt['Result'], elt['kwargs']['table'], elt['type'], getType(elt['type'])] for elt in lst]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[['Checks/', True, 'cars/', 'check_datatype', 'M1'], ['Checks1/', False, 'cars1/', 'check_datatype1', 'C1']]
```

Comment: Thanks krishna, I have one more use case where a function takes type as argument and returns the corresponding value as per dictionary def getType(self,type):
        check_dict={'check_datatype':'M1','check_datatype1':'C1'
                    }
        return check_dict[test_case_name]   
I want to append this dictionary values M1 and C1 as per the type also in all the lists output. Output should be like below
[['Checks/', True, 'cars/', 'check_datatype','M1'], ['Checks1/', False, 'cars1/', 'check_datatype1','C1']]

Comment: getting unresolved reference error in method getType(elt['type']

Comment: you'll need to check your method `getType`, the method you provided in the comment had `self` which means it belong to a class method but in the above code I just added a non-class method with the same name to show the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if key's value is dictionary or not if you have nested dictionary and then you can traverse it.

```
check_list = [{'datasource_path': 'Checks/', 'Result': True, 'kwargs': {'column_name': 'car_id', 'd_type': 'int', 'table': 'cars/'}, 'type': 'check_datatype'}, {'datasource_path': 'Checks1/', 'Result': False, 'kwargs': {'column_name': 'customer_id', 'd_type': 'str', 'table': 'cars1/'}, 'type': 'check_datatype1'}]
check_list

outer_answer = []

for check_dict in check_list:
    inner_answer = []
    for k,v in check_dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            inner_answer.append(v["table"])
        else:
            inner_answer.append(v)
    outer_answer.append(inner_answer)
            
print(outer_answer)
```

Output:

```
[['Checks/', True, 'cars/', 'check_datatype'], ['Checks1/', False, 'cars1/', 'check_datatype1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution using loops, isinstance(), dictionary keys and enumerate().

```
check_list = [{'datasource_path': 'Checks/', 'Result': True, 'kwargs': {'column_name': 'car_id', 'd_type': 'int', 'table': 'cars/'}, 'type': 'check_datatype'},
              {'datasource_path': 'Checks1/', 'Result': False, 'kwargs': {'column_name': 'customer_id', 'd_type': 'str', 'table': 'cars1/'}, 'type': 'check_datatype1'}]
solution, values = [], []

for i, item in enumerate(check_list):
    for key in item.keys():
        if not isinstance(check_list[i][key], dict):
            values.append(check_list[i][key])
    solution.append(values)
    values = []
print(solution)
```

Output equals to :

```
[['Checks/', True, 'check_datatype'], ['Checks1/', False, 'check_datatype1']]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use nested for-loops, you will have to check if your value is a dict or not and then choose which key. This can be done by this code:

```
res = [[(value["table"] if isinstance(value, dict) else value) for value in d.values()] for d in check_list]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[['Checks/', True, 'cars/', 'check_datatype'], ['Checks1/', False, 'cars1/', 'check_datatype1']]
```